How do I create conditional styling on a Vue Component if the stylings need to come from a CSS theme file?
I am trying to get the IconText to turn white and stay white whenever the outer div (MyComponent) has a color of black; otherwise, the IconText should stay whatever var(--COLOR_WINDOWTEXT) is. It needs to be COLOR_WINDOWTEXT because we can change the theme of the overall program and the var(--COLOR_WINDOWTEXT) will have different values depending on that theme.
How do I temporarily overwrite a styling and then revert it back to an externally included CSS var?
<!-- @format -->
<template>
    <div class="MyComponent" :class="[StatusClass]">
        <div class="IconText">
            {{ displayText }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import baseComponent from '../BaseComponent/BaseComponent.vue'
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

const MyStatusComponent = defineComponent({
    name: 'MyStatusComponent',
    extends: baseComponent,
    props: {
        //WIKI: The fully defined path name of the status variable, an empty string means no variable.
        VARIABLE: { type: String, default: '' },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            varValue: undefined as string | undefined,
            clrValue: undefined as string | undefined,
            txtValue: undefined as string | undefined,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        tick() {
            if (this.VARIABLE) {
                const val = this.getVariable()
                if (val) {
                    this.varValue = val.sValue() ?? ''
                } else {
                    this.varValue = undefined
                }
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        displayText(): {
            return 'text'
        }
        StatusClass(): string {
            if (this.varValue !== undefined && this.varValue != "?") {
                const data = JSON.parse(this.varValue);
                this.clrValue = data.clr;
                this.txtValue = data.txt;
                switch (this.clrValue) {
                    case 'blue': return 'statusBlue'
                    case 'red': return 'statusRed'
                    case 'black': return 'statusBlack'
                }
            }
            return 'statusGrey'
        },
    },
})
export default MyStatusComponent
</script>

<style scoped>
.MyComponent {
    color: v-bind(StatusClass);
}

.IconText {
    color: var(--COLOR_WINDOWTEXT); /* ?? I need help understanding what needs to be overriding what here. */
    font-size: var(--FONT_SIZE_LRG_TEXT);
}

.statusBlue {
    background-color: var(--COLOR_STATUS_BLUE);
}
.statusRed {
    background-color: var(--COLOR_STATUS_RED);
}

.statusBlack {
    background-color: var(--COLOR_BLACK_TRUE);
}
</style>


Think in terms of classes instead of style rules? E.g. .statusBlack .IconText { color: #fff }
